# ¿Cómo hacer que un div parpadee de color cada 2 segundos?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Me gustaría me pudieran ayudar tengo un div que quiero que parpadee de color amarillo si el numero ingresado esta dentro del rango 5 al 8 o si esta dentro del rango de 9 en adelante parpadee de color rojo,

hasta ahora solo tengo que cuando detecta un numero solo hace cambiar al color correspondiente al div pero no hace que el color parpadee cada 2 segundos.

```js
$( "#boton" ).click(function() {
  var input = $('#input').val(); 
 $('#numero').text(input);
 
  if(input<=8 && input>5)
  {
    $("#principal").css("background-color", "yellow");
  }
  else if(input>=9)
  {
    $("#principal").css("background-color", "red");
  }
  else
  {
  $("#principal").css("background-color", "white");
  }
});
```

```css
.estilo{
border-style: solid;
width:100px;
height:100px;
text-align:center;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='input' placeholder="Ingrese un numero">
<button id="boton">Aplicar</button>
<br><br>

<div class="estilo" id="principal">
<p>Valor</p>
<h3 id='numero'></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, @Ferns. Cuando dices **...que el color parpadee cada 2 segundos...**, ¿te refieres a que se quede pardeando de forma permanente cada dos (02) segundos? , o ¿simplemente parpadee en el momento en el que se muestre el número en la caja?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necesitas un temporizador, un setTimeOut
Si no he entendido mal debe parpadear (cambiar de color) cada 2 segundos.
Este código te puede servir.
Los códigos de color con palabras no sirven porque el css es leído como código rgb(), por eso te ongo las globales yellow, red, white.

```
var tempor;
var yellow = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
var red = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
var white = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

$( "#boton" ).click(function() {
  var input = $('#input').val(); 
 $('#numero').text(input);
 
  if(input<=8 && input>5)
  {
     clearTimeout(tempor);
     tempor = parpadeo (yellow,white)
  }
  else if(input>=9)
  {  
     clearTimeout(tempor);
     tempor = parpadeo (red,white)
  }
  else
  {
    clearTimeout(tempor);
    $("#principal").css("background-color", white);
  }
});

function parpadeo(color1, color2)
{
   let colorAct = $("#principal").css("background-color");
   if (colorAct == color1)
       {
       $("#principal").css("background-color", color2);
       }
   else 
      {
       $("#principal").css("background-color", color1);
      } 
   tempor=setTimeout (parpadeo, 2000, color1, color2); 
   return tempor    
}
```

Es una posible solución, otra sería usar colores globales y cambiar valores en los if. Pero básicamente es el mismo mecanismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @juan si me funciono eso era lo que necesitaba.